# Autodesk Eagle: How to design predetermined breaking points / line of breakage

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, eaglecad, pcb-fabrication

How can you best design a line of breakage in Autodesk EAGLE that makes it possible to break the individual PCBs easy by hand?

Please see here what I would like to do (blue lines are the lines of breakage):
[image]

Comment: You should contact your PCB fabricator to find out which layer they want these lines on.

Comment: @RoyC thank you for your comment, will do so and get back with the answers.